# PostThreadMessage from target thread

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

Today, I've seen a code like:

```
void Foo()
{
    MyMsgStruct myMsg;

    /* omission for simplicity */

    /* send to update thread */
    PostThreadMessage(myThreadId, myMessage, (WPARAM)myMsg, NULL);
}
```

What happens when `Foo()` is called from the same thread as `myThreadId`, i.e. **from the same thread that's supposed to be the target thread**? Is it a performance issue or just bad written code or both?

I believe it may affect performance since I believe it would queue the message to the thread's queue instead of just doing what it's supposed to do, therefore slowing the program a little.

Thread safety is not my concern **for this question**.

Comment: Some further background on PostThreadMessage here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/225755/PostThreadMessage-Demystified

Comment: A side note: be careful when posting messages that refer to automatic variables like `myMsg` - unless it is a scalar integer variable and is being passed by value in `wParam`, an automatic variable might get destroyed before the recipient thread is able to retrieve and process the message. This is especially true when posting to the same thread since no message processing would occur before `Foo()` returns and `myMsg` gets destroyed (unless a message pumping loop is present but not shown here). Heap allocation solves this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing very special, it just takes a while before whatever code is supposed to run will be called.  Just a delay, it doesn't necessarily make your program slower.  Sometimes you do it on purpose, like wanting to respond to a Windows message but doing it right away causing re-entrancy issues.

Using PostThreadMessage should however almost always be avoided.  Really Bad Things happen when the thread also creates windows, almost always the case since you tend to post to the UI thread to get code to, say, update a window.  Messages fall in the bit bucket whenever a modal loop is entered.  Like the one that is used to resize a window.  Or displays MessageBox.  Always favor posting to a window instead, the message cannot get lost.  Do check the return value of PostMessage().

Creating a dummy invisible window whose window procedure handles these messages is generally a good idea.  You now also have a way to check if you need to post or can execute directly with SendMessage.  Compare GetWindowThreadProcessId with GetCurrentThreadId.

Comment: There's only 1 window and the thread is a worker thread, therefore there's no danger regarding UI thread. I've read about many issues with `PostThreadMessage()` and windows, and yeah, it can create more problems than it solves.

Comment: No, one window is more than enough to cause this problem.  Just don't do it.  If you don't want to create the hidden window then just use that one window.

Answer (score 3):

The message goes into the message queue of the target thread ID, regardless of which thread is calling `PostThreadMessage()`.  It is perfectly valid for a thread to post messages to itself.  The message will be processed when the thread pumps its message queue for new messages.  Sometimes a thread really may want to have a delayed action, so a posted message is good for that.  If a thread wants to do something immediately, there is no point in calling `PostThreadMessage()`, just perform the operation directly.  There is no equivalent to `SendMessage()` for thread messages.