# MFC Send message to MAIN thread (rather than a window)?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, mfc

I'm writing a GUI application for Windows using MFC and C++.

So I need to send messages to my MAIN thread from my worker thread to tell it to update my GUI. However I'm not sure how to send a message to the actual MAIN thread rather than a Window. As it is I can see it is in the MAIN thread when it receives the message but I am not sure if this is guaranteed or just luck.

In worker:

```
PostMessage( *myTestToolDlg, WM_YOU_HAVE_DATA,UPDATE_GUI, 0 );
```

In application window:

```
LRESULT CTestToolDlg::OnData(WPARAM wp, LPARAM )
```

Does this somehow mean that?

Comment: PostThreadMessage?  Anyway, you have a GUI anyway, so you could cretae a simple, hidden window and PostMessage to that.  It can then SendMessage the data onto any other windo you might wish - you could pass the required handle, (or window pointer), in LPARAM, if it varies.

Comment: +1 on what @MartinJames said. Posting thread messages to GUI threads is not recommended because thread messages are swallowed by modal loops, and GUI threads have lots of modal loops. Create a hidden window and post to the window.

Comment: Technically, there's no _main_ thread in Windows, but that's not the point anyway. You want to send a message to the thread which can update your GUI. Each window has an associated thread, and apparently your app (like most) runs all windows on the same thread. That means you can send the message to any window.

Answer (score 1):

You can get your main thread's thread id by using something like `threadId = GetCurrentThreadId();` in **the main thread**, and then send a message to it by calling `PostThreadMessage(threadId, ...)` **from your worker thread**.

However, as Hans Passant said -> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17931913/postthreadmessage-from-target-thread) <-, you should avoid using `PostThreadMessage` to send messages to UI threads, and should better send messages to its window.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify a ListBox or ListView directly, you can use `SendDlgItemMessageA()`

Example :

`char const* pChar = "My text to be updated";`

`SendDlgItemMessageA(hWindow, IDC_LISTBOX, LB_DELETESTRING, 0, 0);`

`SendDlgItemMessageA(hWindow, IDC_LISTBOX, LB_INSERTSTRING, -1, (LPARAM)pChar);`