# mfc c++ send a custom user message with postmessage from a working thread to main ui thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc, visual-studio-2015, postmessage

Using Visual Studio 2015 (Community Edition) & MFC C++ project. I have a worker
thread where I wish to use PostMessage() function to send data from this thread to the main UI thread (where my CDialog resides) yet in the same class, that I
want to receive this message.

In the MyComm.h file, I have the following:

```
#define WM_USERRESPONSE WM_APP + 2000

class MyComm: public CDialog
{
  ...
  CWnd* m_pParent;
  static BOOL m_bThreadKill;
  static CWinThread* pThread;
  static CEvent* pEvent;
  static CEvent m_ThreadKillEvent;
  ...
  static UINT MyThreadProc(LPVOID pParam);
  ...
  afx_msg LRESULT OnResponse(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
  ...
};
```

In my MyComm.cpp file, I have the following:

```
MyComm::MyComm(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(IDD_PPAGE_COMMAND, pParent)
{
  m_pParent = pParent;

  pEvent = new CEvent(FALSE, FALSE);

  if ((pThread = AfxBeginThread(MyThreadProc, this)) == NULL)
    AfxMessageBox("Could not Create Read Thread!");

  pThread->m_bAutoDelete = FALSE;
  m_ThreadKillEvent.ResetEvent();
  m_ReadThreadDead.ResetEvent();
  running = 1;
}

UINT MyComm::MyThreadProc(LPVOID pParam)
{
  MyComm *pMyHndl = ((MyComm*)pParam);
  string s = "I would like this string posted";
  BOOL b = false;

  b = ::PostMessage(pMyHndl->GetSafeHwnd(), WM_USBRDRESPONSE, 0, 
       (LPARAM)&s);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(MyComm, CDialog)
    ON_MESSAGE(WM_USERRESPONSE, &MyComm::OnResponse)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

afx_msg LRESULT MyComm::OnResponse(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  MyStruct* p = (MyStruct*)lParam;
  ...
}
```

Note I abbreviated some of this to stay on topic.

In debugging this (there is much more code than this), I verify that the thread starts, I execute this PostMessage() function which returns true. I never get to
the OnResponse() function that is intended to be the recipient. I am not sure 
why..(??)..

Some thoughts. It is true that the class MyComm is in the the same class yet is 
not the dialog thread, yet is spawned by it and is derived from CDialog. This 
may not be sufficient?? I admit, I am still somewhat new to threads via MFC 
programming paradigm. Any help is appreciated.

Maddog

Comment: Although not causing your delivery issue, will the string 's' still exist when the message is delivered?  Will it not be RAII'd away when MyThreadProc() returns?

Comment: Sorry, in the real code the thread never returns (i.e while (1)...) or until killed.

Comment: In my case this string is a buffer created when the thread is spawned.

Comment: Umm.. OK, so this buffer, it cannot be overwritten before the main thread handles it?

Comment: Is it possible to use **SendMessage** instead? That wait you wait until the buffer has been used by the handler. Then you can carry on ...

Answer (score 1):

Today, I did find the answer to this problem.

It is because the class where the thread is started is not a class tied to a
window yet, is spawned by one with a window. So a subtle nuance on `pMyHndl`
is necessary. If in the `POSTMESSAGE()` I instead use `pMyHndl->m_pParent`
in place of where m_pParent points to the Parent class (one with window).
This code was receiving the message now that the code to receive the message
was moved there. Thanks for all the help everyone.

maddog

Answer (score 0):

- The variable `string s` will not exist after thread finishes. The thread function you've shown is too small, and would exit soon.
- You should ideally start new thread from `OnInitDialog` not in the constructor. The message loop is not created in constructor, but in while in `OnInitDialog`.
- Check that message code is correct. Your code has both: `WM_USBRDRESPONSE` and `WM_USBRDRESPONSE`

Comment: As I said before the thread in my code never completes until killed. I have found that SendMessage() does not receive either. Second I need to wait for message to post before continuing.  Something I have discovered in another question here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271229/mfc-send-message-to-main-thread-rather-than-a-window) recommends that my PostMessage() send it's message to a window. My current class here is windowless other than being spawned in the dialog class.

Comment: So this explains why the MyComm class does not execute the OnInitDialog() method. So I might need to actually create a hidden window here. Apologies on the signal itself. In my code the message is WM_USBRDRESPONSE. I renamed it here WM_RESPONSE only for simplification. I did not want to put the whole code here because it is over 100 pages long and there are Intellectual Property issues invovled.